# SVN checkout/update --revision - Real difference between them when it's needed do rollback

Tags: svn

I have 2 commands (from documentation):

```
$ svn checkout --revision 1729 # Checks out a new working copy at r1729
…
$ svn update --revision 1729 # Updates an existing working copy to r1729
```

What is the practical difference between them related to rollback needs?
I understand that "`svn checkout` will create new workcopy, when `svn update` updates existing one" but what does it mean in practice?

Will I need resolve conflicts after any of this operations or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, read the documentation: [Version Control with Subversion 1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/). I suggest reading the documentation just because SVNBook has a special section that should answer your question: [SVNBook | Fetching Older Repository Snapshots](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.snapshots).

- [`svn checkout --revision 1729`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) will create a *new* working copy at revision 1729. This will require to transfer all the data from the server.
- [`svn update --revision 1729`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) will update an *existing* working copy to revision 1729. Only changes between the working copy's BASE and rev 1729 will be downloaded in this case.

In case of `svn update` you may be required to solve conflicts if you have local & uncommitted modifications in the working copy.

Comment: thank you, @bahrep ) as I understand from docs you've posted - I should use `svn merge`  to rollback state of files state? In this docs we can read: _Many Subversion newcomers attempt to use the preceding svn update example to “undo” committed changes, but this won't work as you can't commit changes that you obtain from backdating a working copy_

Comment: @mir1217 if you want to revert changes made in revision X, and commit this revert as a new revision, check this chapter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo